# Extending Swing components to run on EDT

Tags: java, swing

For java swing components, is it a good idea to extend and override their constructor and calls to ensure they are always executed on the event dispatch thread?

```
@Override
public void setBackground(final Color c) {
    if(SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
        super.setBackground(c);
    } else {
        //Force it to run on EDT through invokeAndWait or invokeLater
    }
}
```

Also (dumb question); if I run a new Runnable within the EDT, does its run call get executed normally (conventional top-down)?

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Update buttons
        }
    }
    r.run(); // Just runs
}
```

Comment: This looks backwards. You should be testing the code that makes the Swing calls not so much the within the Swing GUI classes themselves. Your 2nd bit of code makes no sense as it achieves nothing.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Is it good practice to do within the Swing components itself or create extended components that do so? I'm of the opinion that it would encourage lazy coding where developers would not put stuff in the correct thread properly. The 2nd code also confuses me as I see it called in the else block of the first code. I just wanted to double check that it doesnt do anything special like call the run last or something (invokeLater).

Comment: you don't need to do that. constructing swing components can be done on any thread - the calls to update/paint and a few others *must* be done on the swing event thread.

To your second point: You are just building a runnable object and call the run method. You are not starting a Thread

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer Doesn't construction of swing components call paint especially when I pass in a data model? I recall some q&as here that state they should be constructed in EDT.

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer no, that's incorrect. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html

Comment: Most Swing components don't do this because it's slower and can cause unexpected results and possible race conditions, swing places the responsibility for doing this on the caller

Comment: @Baikol A Swing won't paint a component until it's realised on the screen, this typically occurs when the component is added to a container, which is attached to a native peer, it's not bad practice to do thus within the EDT to ensure it's safe, but if you're careful (and understand the API) you can and configure Swing components of the EDT, but, once they are realised on the screen, must only be accessed from the EDT

Comment: @JB Nizet : it worked fine for the last 15 years or so, but, yes in general you should do all manipulations in the EDT. 
If swing devs decide to break that behavior (of constructing an initial UI from the main thread, for example), they will break a lot of existing swing code.